# AngularJS/UI-Router: How do I use one controller with multiple named views?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have a child state that fills up named views in the parent state (header, content). They both share the same data, however, and I don't want make a redundant second controller but seems like that's one of my only options. I could just use one view but it would then have too much markup which looks messy.

I read the docs [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) and the example they showed is for each view in the state to have it's own controller.

This is not ideal for my scenario. For example, ui-router says I have to do this:

```
.state('root.profile', {
    url: '@:slug',
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-header.html',
            controller: 'ProfileHeaderController as profileHeader'
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-body.html',
            controller: 'ProfileBodyController as profileBody'
        }
    }
});
```

.. and I'd much rather do this:

```
.state('root.profile', {
    url: '@:slug',
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-header.html'
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-body.html'
        }
    },
    controller: 'ProfileController as profile'
});
```

The second option works better for me because as I said they share the same data and I would rather not reproduce a lot of the same logic twice, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

I am already using a service for the one controller. I wouldn't want to have to create another service just to store one set of values to use in both controllers cause that's still not really DRY.

Is there any work-around for something like this?

Comment: This might help you.
http://codepen.io/ahsx/pen/mDcEd

Comment: Hmm yeah it works, thanks, but I can't use it because it doesn't really follow my modular structure. I'd have to add the controller into the module file, which is no bueno :D

Comment: For better understanding, refer https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you code examples, I don't see how this statement is false: *"they share the same data and I would rather not reproduce a lot of the same logic twice"*.

1) ***they share the same data***: Since you have a service, I assume the service stores the current data state, which means that the controllers do share the same data.

2) ***rather not reproduce a lot of the same logic twice***: Your views are referencing the same controller, but different instances, which means that you don't have to reproduce any logic.

*"I am already using a service for the one controller. I wouldn't want to have to create another service just to store one set of values to use in both controllers"*.
If you would make that services a factory, which is a singleton, the same instance would be passed in to each controller that uses the factory-service.

However, I see one possible solution you could do for resolving data and defining controller as a parent to the profile state. This, by having another state between `root` and `root.profile` state. In the example below the two views (`profile-body.html` and `profile-header.html`) can now use the same instance of the `ProfileController`.

```
.state('root', { .. })
.state('root.profile', {
    abstract:true,
    controller:'ProfileController as profile',
    resolve: {
       profile:function(yourProfileDataService) {
           //Resolve profile data
       }
    }
})
.state('root.profile.view', {
    url: '@:slug',
    views: {
        'header': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-header.html'
        },
        'content': {
            templateUrl: 'app/profile/profile-body.html'
        }
    }
});
```

As seen in the example, I also suggest the usage of the resolve property which resolves the data before instantiating the controller, and then injects it into the controller. [Resolve docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @cbass. I can't use this method because I do not want to resolve the data to the controller because of the delay. Currently doesn't work well with my setup from a UI/UX point of view. The act of placing an abstract parent state for the controller (minus the resolve), however, is a good solution.